# Getting the "Created" timestamp of a PDF file in the CLI

Tags: command-line, pdf

I'd like to know if there's a CLI command to get the "Created" timestamp from the "Document" tab (from file properties of a PDF) in the CLI?

I know that I can use `stat` to get Access/Modified/Changed info from the filesystem, but with the meta-data in the "Document" tab being embedded in the file itself, I'm not sure how to go about extracting it via the CLI.

The reason I need to do this is to create a list of filenames along with "Created" timestamps for about 22,000 PDF files. Obviously, this is something far better suited to the CLI than the GUI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you install the `poppler-utils` package, you can do this using the `pdfinfo` command.  For example:

```
$ pdfinfo OBEX-1.3.pdf 
Title:          Microsoft Word - OBEX13.doc
Author:         Daphne
Creator:        PScript5.dll Version 5.2
Producer:       Acrobat Distiller 5.0.5 (Windows)
CreationDate:   Wed Feb  5 11:12:32 2003
ModDate:        Wed Feb  5 11:12:32 2003
Tagged:         no
Pages:          95
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter)
File size:      545666 bytes
Optimized:      yes
PDF version:    1.3
```

You should be able to extract the creation date from this output using standard tools like `sed` or `awk`.

If you want something a bit more programatic, you could use the `poppler` library directly.  There are bindings for many popular languages including Python (through the `python-poppler` package).

Comment: The `pdfinfo` command has a `-isodates` flag, which will make the dates a bit easier to parse ([ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format).

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to it, but looks like [Exiftool](https://exiftool.org) can extract this. For example:

```
% exiftool -createdate -ext pdf .
```

will output the created date for all PDFs in the current directory. There are some options to [control output format](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#Input-output-text-formatting), including `-csv` and `-json`.